# Toggle the "night light" feature on win 10 using python

Tags: python, windows

I am making sort of a quick access program in python.
so I need to make the night light feature on and off using python.
Did not find anything regarding this anywhere.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: U can do this using the winapi. This should be accesible through python. Here is a working solution I found [github](https://github.com/MarkoMarjamaa/AdjustGammaRamp) You could also find a way to directly access the registry and change the value via the command prompt. cheers

Comment: winapi didnt work,no errors but somehow no nightlight enabled. please can you explain how the second method would work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Same as answer below you have acces to the command prompt. If you dont mind doing stuff in the registry you can try the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333299/how-to-start-night-light-via-command-in-windows-10)

Comment: Good stuff, glad i could direct you to the right place !

Answer (score 2):

You can install [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-BlueLight-Configure-0cfb8b65#content) Powershell function which allows you to control the Night Light by a Powershell command. Using `os.system()` you should then be able to call the function from within a Python script.

Comment: it works for me (up voted) but considering that i need to distribute it to my friends, it would be a bit difficult to achieve that as installing that on all machines is not feasible...

Comment: @psycoxer , Do you need a solution that is fully using python3+ only?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Windows 10 and Python 3.9

```
import winreg

STATUS_PATH = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\CloudStore\\Store\\DefaultAccount\\Current\\default$windows.data.bluelightreduction.bluelightreductionstate\\windows.data.bluelightreduction.bluelightreductionstate"
STATE_VALUE_NAME = "Data"


def get_night_light_state_data():
    try:
        hKey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, STATUS_PATH, 0, winreg.KEY_READ)
        value, regtype = winreg.QueryValueEx(hKey, STATE_VALUE_NAME)
        winreg.CloseKey(hKey)

        if regtype == winreg.REG_BINARY:
            return value
    except:
        pass
    return False


def process_night_light_state_data(byte_array):
    night_light_is_on = False
    ch = byte_array[18]
    size = len(byte_array)

    if ch == 0x15:
        night_light_is_on = True
        for i in range(10, 15):
            ch = byte_array[i]
            if ch != 0xff:
                byte_array[i] += 1
                break
        byte_array[18] = 0x13
        for i in range(24, 22, -1):
            for j in range(i, size - 2):
                byte_array[j] = byte_array[j + 1]
    elif ch == 0x13:
        night_light_is_on = False
        for i in range(10, 15):
            ch = byte_array[i]
            if ch != 0xff:
                byte_array[i] += 1
                break
        byte_array[18] = 0x15
        n = 0
        while n < 2:
            for j in range(size - 1, 23, -1):
                byte_array[j] = byte_array[j - 1]
            n += 1
        byte_array[23] = 0x10
        byte_array[24] = 0x00
        # extend array
        ba = bytearray(1)
        ba[0] = 0x00
        byte_array.extend(ba)
        byte_array.extend(ba)
    return night_light_is_on


def write_data_to_registry(byte_array, night_light_state):
    size = len(byte_array)
    retval = False
    try:
        hKey = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, STATUS_PATH, 0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
        winreg.SetValueEx(hKey, STATE_VALUE_NAME, 0, winreg.REG_BINARY, byte_array[:size])
        winreg.CloseKey(hKey)
        retval = True
    except:
        pass
    return retval


if __name__ == '__main__':

    night_light_is_on = False
    value = get_night_light_state_data()
    size = len(value)
    reg_val = bytearray(size)
    reg_val[:] = value
    if get_night_light_state_data():
        night_light_new_settings = process_night_light_state_data(reg_val)
        write_data_to_registry(reg_val, night_light_new_settings)
```